# Volume of solid bounded by $y=x^3, x=2$ and the x-axis is revolved around the line $x=2$

Tags: calculus

My Attempt (non-washers): $\pi$$\int$ $(y^{2/3}$) dy

How am I wrong? How are shells necessary to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic methods for finding volumes of revolution.

The *washer* method involves an integral where the variable of integration is *position **along** the axis* of revolution (and the integrand is squared). Each infinitesimal part of the integral represents the points in some plane perpendicular to the axis.

The *shell* method involves an integral where the variable of integration is *distance **from** the axis*. Each infinitesimal part of the integral represents the points that share the same distance from the axis (that is, the intersection between a cylinder and the body of revolution.

So your attempt that you claim is "non-washers" $\pi\int y^{2/3}\, dy$ matches the pattern for exactly the *washer* method, and you seem to be confused about which method is what. The reason why your integral is wrong is that it corresponds to rotating around the line $x=0$ instead of $x=2$, as required.

For the right washer integral, you should have had $\pi \int (2-\sqrt[3]{y})^2 \, dy$. This *can* be done, but (for this particular curve and axis) you would end up dealing with a more complicated integrand than you can get away with for shells, so shells is *easier* here.

Answer (score 0):

We proceed with the Cylindrical shell method: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^2 2\pi(2-x)x^3dx$. Note that the formula is: $V = \displaystyle \int_{a}^b 2\pi\cdot  r\cdot hdr$, and in this case, $a = 0, b = 2, r = 2-x, h = f(x) = x^3$.

If you like the Washer method, it is: $V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^8 \pi\left(2-\sqrt[3]{y}\right)^2dy$